# Zipkin using Consul service name

Tags: java, spring, consul, zipkin

For some reason Zipkin is using the Consul discovery name instead of the base spring.application.name property.

```
spring:
   consul:
      discovery:
         prefer-ip-address: true
         instanceId: ${spring.application.name}:${spring.application.instance_id:${random.value}}
```

But I want it to use the non-randomized application name (so myservice instead of myservice-67gg8d368).

If I set the Zipkin property `zipkin.service.name` then Consul throws errors saying it cannot find the service.

I'm unsure why the two are even sharing properties and not just adhering to their own.  I'd like the service to use it's base application name because otherwise Zipkin is hard to use, as it lists every new container as a completely new service, making it very difficult to see over time how code changes have changed timing.

UPDATE:
This is the error I get in my logs if I set the zipkin.service.name

```
[o.s.c.c.d.ConsulDiscoveryClient] : Unable to locate service in consul agent: my-service-91828f2f88f18c3fadf193bfa3ad6d1f
```